# Why does break statement terminate program?

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

I have a break statement to exit the loop in:

```
while (cin >> text){
        if (text == "break"){

            break;

        };

        cout << text << endl;
        words.push_back(text);

    }
```

The problem is that program just stops afterward with

> Exit code: 0 (normal program termination).

Here is my full program:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string text;
    vector<string> words;
    vector<int> indices;
    vector<int> indices_sorted;
    vector<string> words_sorted;


    cout << "type in you're desired Text: ";
    while (cin >> text){
        if (text == "break"){

            break;

        };

        cout << text << endl;
        words.push_back(text);

    }

    int size = words.size();

    for (int i =0; i < size; i++){

        indices_sorted.push_back(words[i].size());


    }

    indices = indices_sorted;
    sort(indices_sorted.end(),indices_sorted.begin());
    cout << "you typed: " << words.size() << " words!";
    int counter = 0 ;
    for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
        while (indices[i] != indices[counter])counter++;

        words_sorted.push_back(words[counter]);
        counter = 0;

        cout << words_sorted[i]<< endl;


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is probably related to your environment. Are you using an IDE? Is it Visual Studio Community on Windows? If so, you probably just need a `std::cin.get();` before your program exits to keep the window open.

Comment: Hey right now im just using this site http://cpp.sh .

Comment: I wrote an answer that "fixes" the bug, by removing the UB, but the last nested loops are probably not doing what you want either. Could you add a description of what that code is *supposed* to be doing?

Comment: @cigien should I add to the code ? Or explain it on the comments? I fixed the remaining code! Thanks for the fix that was really helpful. I thought I could sort from highest to lowest.

Comment: Since the bug doesn't depend on the stuff after `sort`, simply fix that part of the code (and do it in the question, not comments). BTW, you can definitely sort from highest to lowest, but you would write `sort(indices_sorted.begin(),indices_sorted.end(), std::greater{});` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written

```
sort(indices_sorted.end(),indices_sorted.begin());
```

which violates a pre-condition of `std::sort`, which is that the second iterator must be reachable from the first by incrementing it. This won't be the case in your code unless `indices_sorted` is empty (i.e. `begin` is equal to `end`), and so you're invoking undefined behavior.

You need to swap the arguments

```
sort(indices_sorted.begin(),indices_sorted.end());
```

and then your program [works](https://godbolt.org/z/3xcjef7s6)

Comment: Works ... but only (it seems) with two input words. Try with input of `alan kate bob dave break`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Hmm, good point. I'm not sure what the last part is supposed to do, so I'll try and get some clarification.

Comment: Hey the last part is supposed to sort the words from shortest to longest. 
The algorithm is doing that right now be converting to the length in integers, saving that on two vectors and sorting one of them. 
Afterwards the last loop compares sorted and unsorted and if both have the same length passing the position word[counter] to words_sorted. 
In the current Code ther is a bug right now that is that indices already used still can be used. I fixed that by setting the unsorted_lengths[counter] to zero. 
Probably way to much computing for the simple task but I hope this gives clarity!